# XSD 1.0 validation fails for custom type

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xerces, xsd-1.0

This is the definition for my type in the XSD file (using xs:anyURI doesn't work):

```
  <xs:simpleType name="lastNavigType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="qrc\:\/help\/SBBL_[\d]+_[\w]+\.html"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

And this is the attribute which should validate:

```
<xs:attribute type="lastNavigType" name="last-navigated" use="required"/>
```

The XML file has this:

```
<helpviewer last-zoom="12" last-navigated="qrc:/help/SBBL_67_Graph_Terminology.html" bookmarks="" maximized="true">
```

I am trying to use the online XSD validation service at `https://www.softwarebytes.org/xmlvalidation/` which uses Xerces-J as backend, but it says:

```
[Error] sbbl_app_settings.xml:20:118:cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'qrc:/help/SBBL_67_Graph_Terminology.html' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern 'qrc\:\/help\/SBBL_[\d]+_[\w]+\.html' for type 'lastNavigType'.
[Error] sbbl_app_settings.xml:20:118:cvc-attribute.3: The value 'qrc:/help/SBBL_67_Graph_Terminology.html' of attribute 'last-navigated' on element 'helpviewer' is not valid with respect to its type, 'lastNavigType'.
```

On the `regex101.com` page it passes validation. What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

XSD's regular expressions are different from a generic regex.

Colon **":"** and forward slash **"/"** characters don't require escaping.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<helpviewer last-navigated="qrc:/help/SBBL_67_Graph_Terminology.html"/>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="helpviewer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="last-navigated" use="required" type="lastNavigType"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="lastNavigType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="qrc:/help/SBBL_\d+_\w+_\w+\.html"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you -- in the meantime, I discovered that `[\w]` is not interpreted to include the underscore. So I used the following pattern, and this validates: `<xs:pattern value="qrc:/help/SBBL_[\d]+_[\w_]+\.html"/>` I did not know that I didn't have to escape the forward slash.

Comment: According to the spec, escaping the forward slash is not just unnecessary, it is invalid. The processor should have reported an error in your schema here.

Comment: The `regex101.com` site must be adding slashes to my regex (front and back, as delimiters). At any rate, they are marked as errors there if I don't escape them. But I'm glad to know that it isn't necessary. And although escaping characters which do not actually need escaping might be superfluous, I was not aware that this should be considered an error?